# Proper way to handle Android Studio's NullPointerException lint warning

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-studio, lint

I'm new to android/java programming and am confused how to properly deal with this warning.

> Method invocation '' may produce 'Java.lang.NullPointerException'

[image]

Should I be ussing assert to remove the warning?
[image]

Or rather a runtime exception?
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you check for null on the object first, the warning goes away. though you end up with a lot of unnecessary null checking if you are sure something will never be null

Comment: Should I just disable this lint warning?

Comment: I wouldn't as it can maybe bring light to something you might have overlooked but I personally just ignore it when I know something will not really be null

Comment: I have an ocd problem when it comes to warnings :P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I doubt this question can be answered conclusively, as it's a matter of opinion. Or at least I believe so -- an opinion too. :)

I understand you want "0 warnings" (a very laudable goal) but there's probably not a "one size fits all" issue. That said...

Things I believe you should **not** do:

- Use **assert**. While you can add an assert statement, Dalvik ignores them. You can configure an emulator to use them if you want, but not a real device (see [Can I use assert on Android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364910/can-i-use-assert-on-android-devices)). So while it would possibly remove the warning, it's useless in practice.
- Have the method throw `NullPointerException`. This would be a bad idea, generally. In this case, since you're probably *overriding* `onOptionsItemSelected()`, it's not even possible.

Checking for `(variable != null)` is generally the best approach. What to do if it is, though, presents some other options.

- If it's a problem you can *recover* from, i.e. you can continue the application even though the `searchView` isn't there, just do so. For example, just return from the method. It's a good idea to **log** this situation though, so you can spot it while testing.
- Otherwise, if continuing isn't possible, throw an exception. You want to [fail early](http://www.leepoint.net/principles_and_practices/40fail-early-fail-often.html), so that the problem can be easily detected. A reasonable exception for this case would be IllegalStateException (see [Java equivalent to .NET System.InvalidOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381322/java-equivalent-to-net-system-invalidoperationexception)). It basically indicates that this method was executed at an inappropriate time. Be careful though, that as a `RuntimeException`, these exceptions are unchecked, and hence will probably cause the app to crash.

Comment: Your own linked answer states it *is* possible to enable assert keyword on a real device (though obviously only via ADB).

Comment: @TomG AFAIK setprop can only be used on rooted devices. But maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Ooh, you may be right -- I've only used it on rooted kiosk style devices myself. Nevermind!

Comment: The vast majority of these warnings come just after findViewById() calls, which can happen a LOT!  As android programmers we are used to the null-pointer errors that come from these and use them to debug when making changes to layout files.  Having to test Every Single One of these calls is a super pain-in-the-ass.  This new "feature" (old versions of Android Studio don't have this warning) greatly increases code bloat.

Comment: @ScottBiggs luckily you can now disable the warning for certain methods. See my answer below.

Answer (score 28):

I started to use

`@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`

on simple methods where I'm sure that the id is not null.

Comment: Perfect, that's what we want. Disable the check only on methods where we are sure that the id cannot be null.

Comment: Or use this in places where you WANT the null-pointer errors (like in `onCreate`).

Answer (score 8):

What @Herrbert74 suggested it surely working fine, but sometimes it's better to not add a `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` to an entire method (if it's not trivial), a better approach could be to use `//noinspection ConstantConditions` on the warned line.

Those are my rules of thumb:

> - Use `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` when the method is simple
> - Use `//noinspection ConstantConditions` when the method is complex and you need to remove the warning only on a specific line

Comment: Very elegant solution. +1

Comment: My personal opinion //noinspection ConstantConditions is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using `if (Object != null){}` for validating is the proper way. `try {} catch (NullPointerException) {}` is the next solution which is preferred in this case.

If you want to get ride of it, throw an `NullPointerException`. Lint will ignore it in this case. `public void myFunc() throws NullPointerException{}`.

Anyway, good Coding always means validating everything for a possible problem while runtime. Validating `!= null` is just fine and should always be used whenever it's possible null.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588482/android-studio-nullpointer-warnings-notice-in-code-view).

> Warning is not an Error. And the warning which you are talking about
>   says "it may produce", don't say 'it must produce'. So choice is
>   yours. Either add null check or not
>
> So, If you are sure that findViewById in your code will never be cause
>   of NPE, then don't add the null check.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer using try{ }catch{ } simply because it is more elegant. However, it does add a lot of bulk to your code, if you imagine putting every, possible, NULL value into a try catch (if they are not next to each other)

Answer (score 1):

As @matiash pointed out there is no one-size-fits-all solution.

For me a good compromise was to disable `NullPointerException` warning for all calls to `findViewById()` and keep it for other method calls. That way I take responsibility for checking the resource ids but still get a benefit of getting warnings if I make other mistakes.

To achieve this I added `_ -> !null` method contract with Android Studio quick fix menu.

The action generated a following file file at `android/support/v7/app/annotations.xml` in my project root.

```
<root>
  <item name='android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity android.view.View findViewById(int)'>
    <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
      <val val="&quot;_ -&gt; !null&quot;" />
    </annotation>
  </item>
</root>
```

**Update:**
Unfortunately it doesn't survive Android Studio restarts :-(
External annotations are really useful so I hope I'll figure out a way to make Android Studio load them after restart.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `Objects.requireNonNull()` which is a good way IMO. As @matiash mentioned, this is not a fool-proof way for every use case, but where you are sure that data won't be `null`, you can use this approach to get rid of the warning. And if it does fail for some unknown reason, you will get `NullPointerException` which you will get anyway without using this.

```
// before
cal.setTime(date);

// after
cal.setTime(Objects.requireNonNull(date));
```