# Is it recommended to check view for null with every findViewById call?

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

When inflating an element with `findViewById`, Android Studio always warns me that my inflated view may return null

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);
```

and suggests I do something like surround with my statement with a null check:

```
if (v != null) {
    mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
}
```

Is it recommended to always do the mentioned null check before inflating an element?

**EDIT**: Adding lint pictures

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this warning and move ahead with your code if you are sure that the id you are passing does exist within your applications context, if you are not sure then its better to do a null check before accessing the elements in this view because

```
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);
```

will return null in case "R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery" is incorrect or invalid renderring v as null .

Thus an attempt like this

```
     mGridView = (GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

may result in a null pointer exception

Answer (score 4):

I think you should never do that.

If you do that you are masking a logic error in your program, in case you are passing a wrong id to your findView.

If you are passing a correct id but for any reason inflater returns null that's Android problem (that will never actually happen) and you also should do nothing.

I think this warning does not come from Android Lint.

Comment: Added images showing the lint warnings I am getting inside Android Studio.